# Bigquery or Pyarrow for string computations. Are there published benchmarks?

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, pyarrow

I have datasets on BigQuery that began life as Json strings.... The schema is <Timestamp, String> but the details are hidden in that String as a Json dictionary, e.g.:

```
2022-01-01 10:11:12.123 UTC, {"DataType1":[46.2], "DataType2":[1002.3],....} 
2022-01-01 10:12:12.123 UTC, {"DataType1":[96.1], "DataType2":[1004.6],....}
```

As part of a Google Cloud Run, I need to extract a dozen variables over hundreds of thousands of timestamps....

What works is to use BigQuery and do a few `JSON_EXTRACT(Data,"$.DataTypeX") As DataTypeX` commands and that gets me (via an intermediate Pyarrow file) a Pandas table full of columns like `[[46.2],[96.1],...]` and then I can do a lambda expression to finally arrive at `[46.2, 96.1,...]`. Great. But is it the fastest?

What I've also tried is to do more on BigQuery, specifically, for each variable do
`CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(Data,"$.DataTypeX"), '[\[\]]', "") AS FLOAT64) As DataTypeX`

This gets me straight to Pandas column of floats [46.2, 96.1, etc]. Which is cool (and seems faster - benchmarking now.)

So here's my question: I see that Pyarrow also supports regexp expressions on Strings. Is there likely to be any efficiency advantage to a regexp on the intermediate Pyarrow file instead of doing the regexp inside BigQuery? More generally, are there any published benchmarks on using Pyarrow for intermediate computation instead of doing it with BigQuery?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of published benchmarks. It isn't clear from you example but if the end goal one column per data type and the limit is 100000 rows I'd expect you could optimize this process in pyarrow one way or another to be as fast or just as fast in bigquery. Bigquery really shines with very large datasets where you get a large benefit for it automatically parralelizing across machines.  For things that can be run on a single machine pyarrow will be competitive because it's core mostly delegates to c++.  If your goal is end to end speed here you might also want to look at BQ's BI engine.